# How can I filter out participants who have not completed both of my questionnaires?

Tags: r, dplyr

when calculating N for my 2 questionnaires, they are different. I would like to filter out participants who have completed both questionnaires and not skipped by the second one.

```
quest_distinct <-  quest_data %>%
  group_by(user_id, q_id) %>%
  filter(session_id == min(session_id), endtime == min(endtime)) %>%
  filter(row_number() == 1) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(user_status %in% c("guest", "registered"))
```

this is the code I have used so far to filter out test sessions.

Comment: Please show a small reproducible exxample with `dput` and the expected output so that it is easier to crosscheck

Comment: Hi Laura, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please do not post screenshots of your data. Instead, [edit] your question with the output of `dput(quest_data)` or `dput(head(quest_data))` if your data is very large. You can use three backticks (`) to improve formatting. See [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/) for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `dplyr`, you can `group_by` `user_id` and use `n_distinct` on `quest_id` (or `q_id` - it is unclear based on previous post of data and code above). This assumes that `quest_id` is a unique value for each questionnaire. `n_distinct(quest_id)` will give you the count of unique questionnaires. If that value is 2, then that user has data for 2 different questionnaires, and you can `filter` to keep that user's data in your output. If you use `dput` with your sample data as suggested in the comments, we can probably provide additional assistance and demonstrate with your data.

```
library(dplyr)

quest_data %>%
  group_by(user_id) %>%
  filter(n_distinct(quest_id) == 2)
```